# Sebcha Touch Select-field loading issue

Tags: javascript, extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2, sencha-touch-2.1

I'm using select fiield to load countries in my project. I load data from database. It works perfectly when I use autoload:true in my store.
But, it isn't loading when I use autoload : false and load it manually.

Sample caode is attached,

Thanks in advance.

Store

```
Ext.define("MyProject.store.CountryStore", {    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
    storeId: "countryStore",
    config: {
        model: "MyProject.model.CountryModel",
        autoLoad: false, //this is the issue
        header: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
        },
        proxy: {
            type: 'ajax',
            url: MyProject.Config.config.webService + 'GetCountries',
            //extraParams: {
            //    sessionId: sessionId
            //},
            reader: {
                type: 'json',
                rootProperty: 'd.countries'
            },
            actionMethods: {
                create: 'POST',
                read: 'POST',
                update: 'POST',
                destroy: 'POST'
            },
            writer: {
                encodeRequest: true,
                type: 'json'
            }
        }
    }
});
```

controller

```
var CountryStore = Ext.create('MyProject.store.CountryStore', {                            });


            CountryStore.getProxy().setExtraParams({
                sessionId: sessionId
            });
            CountryStore.load({
            });
```

view

```
{                xtype: 'selectfield',
                name: 'country',
                label: 'Country',
                store: 'CountryStore',
                valueField: 'code',
                displayField: 'name',
                placeHolder: 'Select your country'
}
```

model

```
Ext.define("MyProject.model.CountryModel", {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    config: {
        idProperty: 'Id',
        fields     : [
             { name: 'code'},
             { name: 'name'}
        ]
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are use controller's store when setting store as name, it's a global store for all views of controller. If you want to use user definition store you need pass it to view.

```
Ext.define('YourProject.controller.YourController', {     
    ...

    sessionId: 'someId',

    init: function () {
        var me = this;

        me.control({
            scope: me,

            'yourviewname': {
                afterrender: me.onViewAfterRender
            }
        });

        me.callParent(arguments);
    },

    onViewAfterRender: function(view) {
        var store = view.getStore();

        if (store) {
            store.getProxy().setExtraParams({
                sessionId: sessionId
            });

            store.load();
        }
    }

    ...
});

Ext.define('YourProject.view.YourView', {
    ...
    alias: 'widget.yourviewname',
    requires: ['YourProject.store.CountryStore'],

    initComponent: function() {
        var me = this,
            countryStore = Ext.create('YourProject.store.CountryStore', {});

        Ext.applyIf(me, {
            ...

            items: [
                {
                    xtype: 'selectfield',
                    name: 'country',
                    label: 'Country',
                    store: countryStore,
                    valueField: 'code',
                    displayField: 'name',
                    placeHolder: 'Select your country'
                }
            ]
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the quick reply. Isn't there any other method to do it? Because I need to keep my view clean(without any functions). Isn't there anyway to do it in controller?

Comment: i add business logic in controller

Comment: That's correct. I'm also going to do that. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it finally :)

When I set store from controller it works :)

`myView.items.items[9].setStore(CountryStore)`;